# Safari Select Box Styling Bug?

Tags: css, safari, styles

I'm getting a wierd bug in Safari 5.0.5 for windows.  When I apply my styles the down arrow in the select box button disappears.  I tried removing classes and it seems multiple classes trigger the bug. Any help would be much appreciated.  You can see an example at http://jsfiddle.net/fbsRY/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full solution, but I did find more details about the problem at http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=179464.  It seems that it might be a bug related to the Windows Classic Theme.  I'm kind of a geek that way.  Love my flat gray interface :)

Comment: OK, I just confirmed this by switching back to the standard Windows 7 theme. It appears to be a glitch with Safari's rendering in Windows Classic theme.  If any safari dev's are reading, maybe this could get fixed in a later update?  At any rate this should be a pretty edge case.  Not sure how many Windows Classic Theme users out there are using Safari as there default browser.  Guessing it's a pretty tiny audience.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably style select elements using CSS as browsers try to stick to the operating systems defaults.  If you MUST style these elements, you'll probably have to find a JS based alternative.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Styling form elements in general is a pain and faking them with JavaScript is the only good way to get any considerable control over them, especially cross-browser / OS.

Comment: I generally try to minimize the use of JavaScript on my sites to only must haves. In this case I wouldn't classify it a must have so I'll probably just give a little on the CSS control in favor of using the standard form control.